# script-src contains an invalid source: ''wasm-eval' while using web worker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chrome-app-developer-tool

The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''wasm-eval''. It will be ignored.[image]

Answer (score -1):

[There is](https://github.com/googlearchive/chromedeveditor/issues/4096) an issue where it is stated that "I found a fix: I removed the code for the loading screen because the chrome update removed the function where the loader goes away when the page is done loading"